# cleanup (with delete) in a thread fails

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17

Why using delete in a thread fails, but not if called synchronously ?

```
class dummyclass{};

main()
{
    vector<dummyclass*> testlist{};
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        auto value = new dummyclass();
        testlist.push_back(value);
    }
    thread cleanuptest([&]() {for (auto x : testlist) delete x;}); // fails (abort())
}
```

EDIT/COMMENT

`detach` and `join` are the right solutions.

In the case `main()` is actually a method in a bigger program, which continues to live, `detach()` is interesting.

In the case of unit tests, then calling `join()` in the destructor of the class to test is cleaner.

Comment: You may want to cleanuptest.join() before continuing on. What if the thread fails to delete all the memory before the program moves on or is forcibly terminated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your program is that your `main()` function exits before the `cleanuptest()` thread has a chance to run to completion, taking the `testlist` object with it.  So when `cleanuptest()` runs, it will likely be trying to access a `vector` that has already been destroyed (or is in the process of being destroyed, depending on the timing of when the threads execute; they are running asynchronously with respect to each other so their relative timing is indeterminate).

The other problem (which is likely the source of the `abort()` call) is that the `std::thread` destructor is detecting that you are destroying the `thread` object without having called either `join()` or `detach()` on it first, which is [considered a programming error](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/%7Ethread).

The fix is easy, just add this line to the bottom of `main()`:

```
cleanuptest.join();
```

The `join()` method won't return until the child thread has exited, so it will guarantee that `testlist` remains valid until the child thread is done using it.

Comment: Now, that being said, creating a thread `cleanuptest` and then immediately calling `cleanuptest.join()` on it is not very different from just calling the underlying function directly in `main` with no threading whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

Your main is finishing before the thread has a chance to finish which is causing the abort.  You should `cleanuptest.join()` the thread to let it finish before main exits.